# What is the angle between two lines?

Tags: real-analysis

When they ask me the angle between two lines, is it the angle in blue or in red ?

[image]

Comment: Depending on context, it may be either.

Comment: Read comment below written answer: most probably it'd be the blue one, i.e.: the acute one. But as Ivan mentions, this could depend on what you've been given as definition or as what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It's the angle between the two direction vector of the lines (I'm not sure of the name "direction vector", but if the equation is $y=ax+b$, the direction vector is $(1,a)$).

In your case, the red angle is the correct one.

Comment: I beg to difer: the direction vectors could perfectly well be "anchored" at the intersection point and then point upwards. In fact, in most uses in geometry, the angle between two lines is *defined* to be the **acute** one (in case there is such, otherwise the lines are perpendicular to each other), and in this case it'd be *the blue* angle.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I've never see that the angle of two line is the acute one. This is the definition I know, but may be it may depend of the context...

Comment: You can read it here: http://planetmath.org/anglebetweentwolines , or here: http://www.math-only-math.com/angle-between-two-straight-lines.html , (note (ii)) , or here: http://www.tpub.com/math2/5.htm ... In **any source I know** it is defined that way, but that's not important now: why do **you** define the direction vector of $\;y=ax+b\;$ as $\;(1,a)\;$ ? Why not $\;(-1,-a)\;$ , say? Or even the same as you but *normalized*, namely $\;\frac1{\sqrt{a^2+1}}(1,a)\;$ ...?